# Sending data to octomap_server issue

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect, octomap, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys!

I'm having some trouble running rgbdslam (on turtlebot w/ kinect) to generate an octomap **without using the GUI.**

After start the robot and kinect (openni), my steps are

```
>     roslaunch rgbdslam octomap_server.launch
>     roslaunch rgbdslam headless.launch
>     rosservice call /rgbdslam/ros_ui_b pause false
     -- Then capture some frames moving the robot around my lab --
>     rosservice call /rgbdslam/ros_ui_b pause true
>     rosservice call /rgbdslam/ros_ui send_all
```

The problem is: After send all the points captured, i'm able to run: `rosrun octomap_server octomap_saver file.bt` **but file.bt only contains the last frame captured.**

I think that octomap_server is overwriting the data received, so in the end it only contains the last frame. I've tried to change the parameters a lot, but with no success.

Here are the pictures of [octomap_server.launch](http://postimg.org/image/mtjtzfdep/) and [headless.launch](http://postimg.org/image/epbpuoqzl/).

Any suggestion ?

Thanks !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199758/sending-data-to-octomap_server-issue/) by [Thiagopj](https://answers.ros.org/users/19552/thiagopj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-12-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

Your launch-files seem right. I am not sure what the problem is. See my answer to [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/200394/problem-using-turtlebot-kinect/).

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2015-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0